# Properties of Weak Convergence of Probability Measures on Product Spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, self-learning, weak-convergence, products

**EDIT:**
*For the Bounty, I made a substantial edit revision concerning the structure of the question, to make it more readable (hopefully). Moreover I added a question on problem 2.7 of  Billingsley’s book.*

---

I have two problems concerning ***weak convergence*** of probability measures in ***product spaces***, that arose from Billingsley’s classic  “Convergence of Probability Measures” (Chapter I, Section 2, Subsection “Product Spaces”).

Below there are the part of the book that made me wonder, the numbered questions I have, plus my thoughts (hidden, in order to lighten the overall immediate reading of the question).

<sub>**Notation:**  $P$ is a probability measure on $T = S' \times S''$, $P_n \Rightarrow P$ denotes weak convergence, while a $P$-continuity set is the family of those sets $A \in \mathcal{S}$ such that $P(\partial A)= 0$, where $\mathcal{S}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $S$, and $\partial A$ denotes the boundary of $A$. Concerning **product spaces**, $\mathcal{T} :=  \mathcal{S}' \times \mathcal{S}''$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of $T$, while $P’$ is the marginal distribution on $\mathcal{S}’$ of $P$ on $\mathcal{T}$, defined as $P’ (A) := P(A \times S’’)$ (and the same applies to $P’’$).</sub>

---

---

**I PART**

The first problem is with the following Billingsley’s statement **in bold**.

*[Theorem 2.8.ii. should be a sort of a partial converse of the – trivial – following proposition, here named in the following way:
**Proposition 1:** If $P_n \Rightarrow P$, then $P^{'}_n \Rightarrow P'$, and $P^{''}_n \Rightarrow P’’$.]*

> Therefore, we have the following theorem, **in which** ***(ii)*** **is an obvious consequence of** ***(i).***
>
> **Theorem 2.8.**
>
> ***(i)*** If $T = S' \times S''$ is separable, then $P_n \Rightarrow P$ if and only if $P_ n (A’ \times A’’) \to P(A' \times  A'')$ for each $P’$-continuity set $A’$ and each $P’’$-continuity set $A''$.
>
> ***(ii)*** If $T$ is separable, then $P^{'}_n \times P^{''}_n \Rightarrow P’ \times P’’$ if and only if $P^{'}_n \Rightarrow P'$ and $P^{''}_n \Rightarrow P’’$.

---

**II PART**

The Second problem concerns problem 2.7 in the book, that reads:

> **Problem 2.7:** The uniform distribution on the unit square and the uniform distribution on its diagonal have identical marginal distributions. Relate this to Theorem 2.8.

---

---

**Questions:**

1. How do we prove (ii)?
   **1.a.** How do we prove the ($\Leftarrow$) direction of (ii)?
   **1.b.** How do we actually use (i) to prove (ii), as Billingsley suggests?
   **1.c.** Is my way of addressing the problem below sound?
2. How do we actually relate problem 2.7 to theorem 2.8?
   **2.a.** Do we actually have to use the setting in the problem to come up with some measure that works as a counterexample of **Proposition 1**, or
   **2.b.** It is enought to notice that the weak limit is now not unique, and hence the converse of **proposition 1** does not hold anymore?

---

---

Here my thoughts on question 1:

> **Attempted proof of (ii):**
>  **(only if)** Assume that $P^{'}_n \times P^{''}_n \Rightarrow P' \times P’’$. Thus, by taking the marginals $P'$, and $P''$ on  $P^{'}_n \times P^{''}_n \Rightarrow P' \times P''$, we obtain that $P{'}_n \Rightarrow P’$, and $P{''}_n \Rightarrow P''$.
>  **(if)** Assume that $P^{'}_n \Rightarrow P'$, and $P^{''}_n \Rightarrow P''$. Let $A' \in \mathcal{S}'$, $A'' \in \mathcal{S}'$ be arbitrary, such that $A'$ is a $P'$-continuity set, and $A''$ is a $P''$-continuity set. *[… and here it ends. I thought that we could use the Portmanteau theorem to get somewhere from the fact that $P^{'}_n \Rightarrow P'$, and $P^{''}_n \Rightarrow P''$, but I really don't know.]*

---

---

As always, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direction that $P_n'\times P_n'' \Rightarrow P'\times P''$ implies the weak convergence $P_n' \Rightarrow P'$ and $P_n'' \Rightarrow P''$ is a special case of Proposition 1, since the marginals of a product measure are the respective factors. We could give a simpler proof for this special case, but I doubt that that would be very enlightening.

To show the other direction, we assume $P_n' \Rightarrow P'$ and $P_n'' \Rightarrow P''$. We use part $(i)$, which tells us that for all $P'$-continuity sets $A'$ and $P''$-continuity sets $A''$ we need to check

$$(P_n'\times P_n'')(A'\times A'') \to (P'\times P'')(A'\times A'').\tag{1}$$

But by our assumption and the Portmanteau theorem, we have $P_n'(A') \to P'(A')$ and $P_n''(A'') \to P''(A'')$, and by limit algebra it follows that

$$(P_n'\times P_n'')(A'\times A'') = P_n'(A')\cdot P_n''(A'') \to P'(A')\cdot P''(A'') = (P'\times P'')(A'\times A''),\tag{1'}$$

so indeed $(i)$ tells us that under our assumption $P_n'\times P_n'' \Rightarrow P'\times P''$.

Without using part $(i)$, we would have to show that $(P_n'\times P_n'')(A) \to (P'\times P'')(A)$ for all $(P'\times P'')$-continuity sets $A$, and there are generally a lot of $(P'\times P'')$-continuity sets that aren't products. Thus $(i)$ reduces the required work, and leaves only the case of product sets to be considered.

I think that answers 1.a. and 1.b. Concerning 1.c., in the "only if" part you should mention that you use Proposition 1, it's better to be explicit. In the "if" part, you have the right idea to use the Portmanteau theorem, but you didn't recognise how to use it.

Problem 2.7. is rather hard, since it's not clear what Billingsley expected there. I think the thing to take away is that a probability measure on a product space is in general not determined by its marginal measures. (But if all but possibly one of the marginal measures of $P$ are point masses, then $P$ is the product of its marginals.) That's in fact not hard to see once you think about it, but it's a tempting mistake.

Let's try to relate it, though. By theorem 2.8., if $P_n$ is a sequence of probability measures on the unit square converging weakly to the uniform distribution $U_{\Delta}$ on the diagonal of the unit square, then the product of the marginals, $P_n' \times P_n''$, converges weakly to the uniform distribution $U_{\square}$ on the unit square. In particular, from $P_n' \Rightarrow P'$ and $P_n'' \Rightarrow P''$ we can **not** conclude that $P_n \Rightarrow P$. The theorem only gives that conclusion if we additionally know that $P_n$ and $P$ are product measures, i.e. $P_n = P_n' \times P_n''$ and $P = P' \times P''$.

Ad 2.a.: We don't get counterexamples to proposition 1, since that proposition is true. What we get are counterexamples to the naïve converse of proposition 1, which would be "If $P_n' \Rightarrow P'$ and $P_n'' \Rightarrow P''$ then $P_n \Rightarrow P$". We can find counterexamples to that not only in the exact setting of problem 2.7 of course, all we need is a measure $P$ that is not a product measure, or a sequence of not-product measures whose marginals converge weakly. That can be constructed as soon as both factor spaces have more than one point.

Ad 2.b.: The weak limit - if it exists - is still unique. The point is that unlike for sequences in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the (weak) convergence of all marginals (analogous to the coordinate projections in $\mathbb{R}^n$) is no longer sufficient to deduce the (weak) convergence of the original sequence - consider $P_{2n} = U_{\Delta}$ and $P_{2n+1} = U_{\square}$ - nor, if the sequence is weakly convergent, to determine the weak limit.

Comment: As always, thanks for the super-amazing answer! In what follows there are some questions (as always it will take time to digest it).

Comment: *In the meantime, just an aside, and I was wondering about your opinion: I find Billingsley's writing quite difficult, in the sense that he is informal in a way that still is formal, but that only real mathematicians can appreciate without getting lost (I never talk with a mathematician, but it seems to me that this is how they communicate, informally, but formally at the same time).*

Comment: It's been a long time since I've looked in any of Billingsley's books, and I don't have any in reach. I don't remember his writing style, I'm afraid.

Comment: I really have problems with how you present the "if" part (I am sorry, but it is a bit too quick for me). I will number the questions I have to try to clarify my problems.

Comment: We want to prove that $(P^{'}_n \times P^{''}_n) \Rightarrow (P' \times P'')$. **1)** Do we apply Portmanteau here, to get that we want to actually prove that for every $A \in \mathcal{T}$, if $(P^{'}_n \times P^{''}_n ) (\partial A) = 0$, then $(P^{'}_n \times P^{''}_n )(A) \to (P^{'} \times P^{''} ) (A)$?

Comment: We assume $P'_n \Rightarrow P'$, and  $P''_n \Rightarrow P''$. **2)** Do we apply *(i)* here to each of them? If so, how? I tried this route, but I ended up with the fact that $P'_n \Rightarrow P'$ is equivalent to the fact that for every $A' \in \mathcal{S}'$, and every $A'' \in \mathcal{S}''$ if $P'(\partial A') =0$ and $P'' (\partial A'')=0$, then $P'_n (A' \times A'') \to P'_ (A' \times A'')$ (and the same applied to $P''$). But then I was lost, because even if what I wrote in question (1) in the previous comment is correct, and I have everything I need, still I only get... *[continues]*

Comment: ... $P'_n (A' \times A'') \to P' (A' \times A'')$, and $P''_n (A' \times A'') \to P'' (A' \times A'')$, and now I don't see how the get $(P'_n \times P''_n) (A' \times A'') \to (P' \times P'') (A' \times A'')$. (of course the problematic product to obtain for me is that of the probability measures). Still regarding this route, I didn't pursue it, because I thought that to apply *(i)* to $P_n \Rightarrow P$, $P$ really has to be a product measure of the form $P := P' \times P''$ in order to sensibly talk about $P'$-continuity sets. Hence it does not apply to $P'$ itself (the same to P'').

Comment: Let me start by answering **2)**. We can't apply $(i)$ to $P_n'\Rightarrow P'$ or $P_n'' \Rightarrow P''$ since in general $S'$ and $S''$ aren't themselves product spaces, and $P_n',P'$ are measures on $S'$, and $P_n'',P''$ are measures on $S''$. The definitions are $P'(A') := P(A'\times S'')$ and $P''(A'') := P(S'\times A'')$, and analogously for $P_n',P_n''$. (All for $A'\in \mathcal{S}'$ and $A'' \in \mathcal{S}''$ of course.)

Comment: Then from the Portmanteau theorem we get that for all $P'$-continuity sets $A'\in \mathcal{S}'$ we have $P_n'(A') \to P'(A')$, and similarly $P_n''(A'') \to P''(A'')$ for all $P''$-continuity sets $A'' \in \mathcal{S}''$. Then by the definition of a product measure, we have $(P_n'\times P_n'')(A'\times A'') = P_n'(A')\cdot P_n''(A'')$, and by limit algebra that converges to $P'(A')\cdot P''(A'')$, which by definition is $(P'\times P'')(A'\times A'')$. Now part $(i)$ of the theorem tells us that $P_n'\times P_n'' \Rightarrow P'\times P''$.

Comment: First of all, let me thank you not only for your super amazing answers (again), but also for your patience. I really (really) appreciate it, and I think your pedagogical skills are just outstanding. Going back to the first part of the question (I'll need a bit to get to the second and think about it), I think that now overall I see what it happening, and why I could not really see it. There is just one thing (rather important) that still troubles me. I wrote in a previous comment that $P:=P'\times P''$. This is wrong, isn't it? Otherwise, **Th.2.8(ii)** would be the converse of **Prop1**...

Comment: ...where the converse of **Prop1** is false (as you wrote in Ad 2.a, which is actually what I meant in my question). Thus, to check if I really see what the problem is all about. Is the all distinction between the theorems that of $$\displaystyle (P'_n \times P''_n) \Rightarrow (P' \times P'') \hspace{1cm}\text{[(ii), True]},$$ vs. $$\displaystyle (P' \times P'')_n \Rightarrow (P' \times P'') \hspace{1cm}\text{[Converse of Prop1, False]}?$$

Comment: In part $(ii)$, we are looking at the situation where $P = P'\times P''$. And **for that situation** we indeed have the converse of proposition 1: if $P = Q\times R$ is a product measure, and $P_n = Q_n \times R_n$ are product measures, then we have $P_n \Rightarrow P$ if and only if $Q_n \Rightarrow Q$ and $R_n \Rightarrow R$. For these measures we have $Q = P'$ and $R = P''$, and $Q_n = P_n',\: R_n = P_n''$, so proposition 1 gives $(P_n \Rightarrow P) \implies (Q_n \Rightarrow Q \land R_n \Rightarrow R)$, and part $(ii)$ of theorem 2.8. gives the other direction.

Comment: The converse of proposition 1 fails if $P$ is not a product measure - that is $P \neq P' \times P''$ - or (inclusive or) infinitely many of the $P_n$ are not product measures. In that case, from $P_n'\Rightarrow P'$ and $P_n'' \Rightarrow P''$ we cannot conclude that $P_n\Rightarrow P$. That's because a probability measure is not determined by its marginals. Part $(ii)$ says that if $(P_n)' \Rightarrow P'$ and $(P_n)'' \Rightarrow P''$ then $(P_n)'\times (P_n)'' \Rightarrow P'\times P''$, but in general we have $P_n \neq (P_n)'\times (P_n)''$ and $P \neq P'\times P''$,

Comment: so that doesn't tell us whether $P_n \Rightarrow P$ or not. Unless $P = P'\times P''$ and $P_n = (P_n)'\times (P_n)''$ for almost all $n$, the weak convergence of the marginals doesn't tell us much about the weak convergence $P_n \Rightarrow P$. That may or may not be the case.

Comment: Maybe (still maybe) I got it! Thus,  three questions. **(1)** Are you telling me that basically the all problem is that some probability measures *over product spaces* are ***not*** actually *product measures*? **(2)** If that's the case, how do we call those *irregular* probability measures over product spaces? **(3)** Notationally wise, does what I wrote in the last comment (i.e. the blabla vs. blabla thing) make sense or it's just idiotic (as I start to think)?

Comment: **(1)** Yes, exactly. With the modification that I'd say _most_ measures on product spaces aren't product measures. If we look at the unit square and the family of probability measures on it that have a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure, the product measures are just the ones whose density has the form $\rho(x,y) = f(x)\cdot g(y)$, where $f,g\colon [0,1]\to [0,+\infty]$ are measurable with $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = 1 = \int_0^1 g(y)\,dy$. A general probability measure there has an arbitrary measurable density $\rho \colon [0,1]^2 \to [0,+\infty]$ with $\iint \rho(x,y)\,dx\,dy = 1$.

Comment: **(2)** We just call them probability measures, the simple straightforward case has a special name. If you think of random variables and their distributions, product measures correspond to the case of _independent_ random variables.

Comment: **(3)** The first part is completely fine. In the second part, $(P'\times P'')_n$ doesn't make much sense. And we have the problem that the real full converse of proposition 1 can't be slickly formulated with such a notation, since in general you can't reconstruct a measure from its marginals, so we can't express $P_n$ by $P_n'$ and $P_n''$ or $P$ by $P'$ and $P''$ - unless they are product measures, and then the converse holds.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot! I think I really start to see this part of the answer. I am afraid I will bother you with some other questions concerning **Problem 2.7**. :)

Comment: Go ahead. But tomorrow, now it's time to sleep for me.

Comment: Indeed, I needed a bit to metabolise the answer, and to come up with some sensible questions concerning exercise 2.7 (numbered in the following), but here there are. :)

Comment: **1)** You write *``That's in fact not hard to see once you think about it, but it's a tempting mistake.''* What is this tempting mistake? Are you repherring to the sentence you wrote in braces? I have problem with the ovrall construction of the period.

Comment: **2)** In the next paragraph, you discuss the example. One thing I don’t see is why we need to compare the uniform on the diagonal and the uniform on the square. If the take-home lesson is the one you write concerning product measures, we could simply focus on one distribution. Or do we need the comparison because the uniform on the diagonal is *a fortiori* a product measure, while that on the unit square it does not have to be a product measure?

Comment: Your last paragraph is a bit cryptic to me, thus I will probably need another month to get it right… :D. More than thanks a lot as always!

Comment: **1)** The tempting mistake (at least I think it's tempting) is to believe that a measure on a product space is determined by its marginals. The parenthetical lists an exception, a situation where the marginals determine the original measure without assuming a priori that it's a product measure. It's probably better to move the parenthetical at the end of that paragraph.

Comment: **2)** The uniform distribution on the diagonal is _not_ a product measure. The uniform distribution on the square is a product measure. The thing is that we have a simple example of a situation where two different distributions - $U_{\Delta}$ and $U_{\square}$ - have the same marginal distributions. And if we know nothing about the sequence $(P_n)$ except that the marginal distributions converge (weakly) to the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, i.e. $P_n'\Rightarrow (U_{\Delta})' = (U_{\square})'$ and $P_n''\Rightarrow (U_{\Delta})'' = (U_{\square})''$, then we can't even tell whether $(P_n)$

Comment: converges weakly to anything, and if it does, we still can't tell to which distribution. A simple example is when $P_n$ alternates between $U_{\Delta}$ and $U_{\square}$. Then the sequences of marginal distributions are constant, so trivially they converge weakly. But the sequence $(P_n)$ of course doesn't converge weakly.

Comment: Great. I think I finally got it! Super-thanks a lot!