# How to generalise inner product to measures without densities

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(E, \mathcal{E}, \lambda)$ be a metric finite measure space, and let $\mu, \nu$ be finite measures with densities $f,g$ with respect to $\lambda$.

Then, I am interested in considering the functional: $$\langle \mu, \nu \rangle = \int_E g d \mu = \int_E fg \;d\lambda = \int f d \nu$$

which has the desired properties of an inner product.

However, I would possibly like to define this product for measures which do not have densities. How could I best generalise this for the case where neither $\mu, \nu$ have densities with respect to $\lambda$?

Inspired by the Lebesgue theory of integration, my best attempt would be to define:

$$\langle \mu, \nu \rangle = \sup \{\rho(E): \rho(A) \le \mu(A) \nu(A) \; \forall A \in \mathcal{E} \}$$

where $\rho$ must be a measure on $(E,\mathcal{E})$.

Does this seem reasonable? If so, is there a more elegant way to write this? It would be very helpful to know before I start trying to prove that this definition coincides with the definition for pairs of measures where at least one has a density w.r.t. $\lambda$.

Comment: Is your attempt a bilinear form?

Comment: The integral $\int_E fg d\lambda$ doesn't have to be finite, even when all three measures are finite and $\mu,\nu$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{M}(E,\mathcal{E})$ denote the space of (signed in the real case, complex in the complex case) measures on $\mathcal{E}$ with finite total variation. Then for $\lambda\in \mathcal{M}(E,\mathcal{E})$, the space of measures which are absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$ is identifiable with $L_1(\lambda)$ via $\mu\mapsto \frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$. So this set is naturally related to first moments. You need further conditions to get finite second moments, which is what you want.

Comment: @jwhite Thanks for pointing that out; I hadn't thought about it. But actually, I am content for the integral to be possibly infinite. However, I would, of course, still wish that the definitions coïncide in this case.

Comment: To better answer your question, what is the goal of constructing $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$?

Comment: @KurtG. I would think so. For my purposes, I believe it suffices for me to only consider positive measures, so let's only consider bilinearity where the constants $a,b$ are non-negative. Then, $\rho \le \mu \nu \iff ab \rho \le (a \mu) (b \nu)$. So I think it is bilinear, just as the Lebesgue integral is linear.

Comment: @jwhite I am considering how $\langle \mu, \nu \rangle $ may be related to the limit of the inner products of sequences of simple functions on $E$ (which could be computed as a finite sum) where $\mu, \nu$ are the weak limits of the distributions of the functions, if they exist. I would expect to be able to show that if $\langle \mu, \nu \rangle$ is infinite, that the sequence of simple inner products also converges to infinity (assuming I land upon a suitable definition).

Comment: By itself, a simple function doesn't have a distribution. I assume you mean the distribution it has as determined by $\lambda$?

Comment: @jwhite Yes, sorry, that would be the one. In other words, the measure with that simple function as its density with respect to $\lambda$.

Comment: An inner product $\langle\mu,\nu\rangle$ must have the following bilinearity properties:
$\langle a\mu, b\nu\rangle=ab\langle\mu,\nu\rangle$ for ***all*** $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $\langle\mu+\sigma,\nu+\rho\rangle=\langle\mu,\nu\rangle+\langle\mu\,\rho\rangle+\langle\sigma,\nu\rangle+\langle\sigma,\rho\rangle\,.$ I do not think your attempt works.

Comment: @KurtG. I know what bilinearity means. I only claimed that this functional had the desirable properties of an inner product i.e. the properties which I desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hypothesis was dead wrong. Consider the example where $E = [0,1]$ and $\lambda, \mu$ and $\nu$ are all the Lebesgue measure. Then, clearly, we wish to have:

$$\langle \mu, \nu \rangle = 1$$

But this is not what we get with the latter definition. Note that if $I_n$ is any interval of width $2^{-n}$, then we must have:

$$\rho(I_n) \le \mu(I_n) \nu(I_n) \le 2^{-2n}$$

$$\implies \rho([0,1]) \le 2^{-n}$$

by countable additivity, and therefore, since $n$ was arbitrary:

$$\rho([0,1]) = 0$$

Intuitively, the issue here is the second definition obliquely refers to measures $\rho$ such that $d \rho \le d \mu \; d \nu$, and the double infinitesimal still gives zero after integrating. It clearly makes sense to wonder if the solution is to integrate twice.

**Revised solution**:

Let $\mu, \nu$ be finite measures on $E$. We define:

$$\langle \mu, \nu \rangle = (\mu \times \nu) (E \times E)$$

where $\mu \times \nu$ is the product measure on $E \times E$, given the product $\sigma$-algebra as usual.

It is clear that this works.

---

Regarding the context of how I wished to apply this with weak convergence of measures, it is quoted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606793/properties-of-weak-convergence-of-probability-measures-on-product-spaces) that if the measure space is separable, then $$\mu_n \Rightarrow \mu, \nu_n \Rightarrow \nu \implies (\mu_n \times \nu_n) \Rightarrow (\mu \times \nu)$$ and this is the result I wished to then prove.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of this problem is to show that if $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, $(t_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ are $\mathcal{E}$-measurable, simple functions which converge (in some mode) to $\mu,\nu$, and if $\langle \mu,\nu\rangle=\infty$, then $$\lim_n \int s_nt_nd\lambda=\infty.$$

Weak convergence (convergence in distribution) does not work for this, even when we restrict to measures which are absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$. For example, take $\lambda$ to be Lebesgue measure on $[-1,1]$ and let $$\mu(A)=\int_{A\cap [0,1]} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}d\lambda.$$ Then $\langle \mu,\mu\rangle=\infty$. We can choose a sequence of simple functions $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ on $[-1,1]$ which converge pointwise to $f$, where $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} & : 0<x\leqslant 1 \\ 0 & : 1<x\leqslant 2,\end{array}\right.$$ and where $s_n|_{[-1,0]}\equiv 0$ for all $n$. We can define $t_n(x)=s_n(-x)$. So $t_n$ is a reflection of $s_n$, and, by symmetry, it has the same distribution as $s_n$. Then $\int s_ns_nd\lambda\to\infty$, but $\int s_nt_nd\lambda=0$ for all $n$, because $s_n,t_n$ have disjoint supports.

We can see from this example that it is not just the distribution of the $s_n,t_n$ (or the $\mu,\nu$) which matter, but also their realizations.

Let $\text{abs}(\lambda)$ denote the set of (signed) measures on $\mathcal{E}$ which are absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$. Then each $\mu\in \text{abs}(\lambda)$ has a density (Radon-Nikodym derivative) $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$. Moreover, $\text{abs}(\lambda)$, endowed with its total variation norm, is isometrically isomorphic to $L_1(\lambda)$. The inner product $$\langle \mu,\nu\rangle = \int f,g d\lambda$$ that you've defined at the beginning of your proof is just the usual inner product on $L_2(\lambda)$.

Since we're concerned about limits (in some mode of convergence) of sequences of (non-negative) simple functions, and convergence in distribution doesn't quite get you where you want to go, the question for how to proceed will depend on what mode of convergence is the right mode. If you chose almost sure convergence (say $s_n\to f$ a.s. and $t_n\to g$ a.s.), you still have non-negative functions $f,g$ and you can still look at $\int fgd\lambda$. In this case, you have $$\int fg d\lambda \leqslant \lim_n \int s_nt_n d\lambda$$ by Fatou's lemma. So if $\int fgd\lambda=\infty$, the inner products of the simple functions also go to $\infty$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This looks really helpful. I'll be able to read it more thoroughly later.

Comment: Hi, thanks again (+1). I had a couple of questions. Why is $f$ defined on $[0,2]$? And it seems to me that although $t_n$ has the same distribution as $s_n$, it does not converge weakly to the same limit. By weak convergence, in this example, I would mean that the values of the integrals (for any bounded continuous function) against the measures given by $(t_n)$ converge to the integral against the measure given by $f$. However, this is not true because if $g$ is, for instance, $\max(0,x)$, then the integral of $g$ against $t_n$ is zero for all $n$, but non-zero for $f$. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: I find the usage of distribution in probability theory to be quite unfortunate sometimes. I believe I am correct in saying that if $\Omega$ is a probability space, there can be e.g. two random variables with the $\text{Exp}(1)$ distribution (and so the "same distribution"), but that this doesn't necessarily mean that the distributions are the same in the sense of weak convergence.